# switch case don't work on page load javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement, case

i have a problem with a switch case in javascript. It don't work the first time when the page is loaded but after it work perfectly and i dont find why ...

look at this  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4j88/3/)

Javascript:

```
      $(".dial").knob({'draw' : function (v) {
                    rotate($('#el27'),this.v,false);


                                                     }});       
    $("#cont>div").each(function() {

                id = $(this).attr('data-id');
                rotate($(this),$(this).attr('data-angle'));
            });

        function rotate (element,degres) {

           var od = element.attr('data-angle');

            element.children(":first").css('transform','rotate('+ degres +'deg)')
                .css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+degres +'deg)')
                .css('-moz-transform','rotate('+degres +'deg)')
                .css('-ms-transform','rotate('+degres +'deg)')
                .css('-o-transform','rotate('+degres +'deg)');
                element.attr('data-angle',degres);
                if (od != element.attr('data-angle')){                
                width = element.width();
                height = element.height(); 
                element.css({'width':height,'height':width});
                };

            switch (degres){                
                    case 0:
                    case 360:
                     element.children(":first").css({
                       '-webkit-transform-origin': '',
                       '-o-transform-origin' : '',
                       '-ms-transform-origin': '', 
                       'transform-origin'    : '',
                        'position':'',
                        'width': element.width(),
                        'height' : element.height(),
                        'top': '',
                        'left': ''
                         });

                    break;
                    case 90:
                   element.children(":first").css({
                       '-webkit-transform-origin': 'top right',
                       '-o-transform-origin' : 'top right',
                       '-ms-transform-origin': 'top right', 
                       'transform-origin'    : 'top right',
                        'position':'absolute',
                        'width': element.height(),
                        'height' : element.width(),
                        'top': element.height() + parseInt(element.css('padding')),
                        'left': element.width() - element.height() + parseInt(element.css('padding'))
                        });
                    break;
}
        }
```

when windows load i can see in debbuger the switch is not tested and after there is no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first run (dom load) you are passing a string to your rotate function (and the switch isn't finding a match), on the dial step you are passing an integer.  You can fix this by calling parseInt here ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s4j88/3/)):

```
$("#cont>div").each(function () {
  id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  rotate($(this), parseInt($(this).attr('data-angle'), 10));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To quote [jQuery document ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."
>   jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside
>   $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object
>   Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included
>   inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire
>   page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

Comment: i just do a copy past form fiddle, the script run when windows is loaded